# Kafka Consumer -- Batch proccess and commit

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Assume that, I have a batch (10 records) from 1 consumer.poll()

I iterate through 10 records. If the process is successful I will call commit(record.offset() + 1). So If the records have I only commit records number 4, 7, 9.

I know that when we commit records number 9 ==> The next records we can poll will be records number 10

What will happen to other records number 1,2,3,5,6,8. Do Kafka have a dead letter queue for them to go into ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. Consumers in Kafka can only consume the last offset.

But you could have a trick and store failed messages in a database or another Kafka topic and process them later.